# One specific client cannot reach one specific server and vice versa

Tags: networking, dns, ping

I currently face the problem, that one specific client with dynamic IPv4 Address cannot communicate with a specific server. Vice versa also doesen't work. That includes pinging, rdp, network shares. As if those two simply do not see each other.
Every other client / server in the domain network can communicate without any problems.

DC is reachable, therefore DHCP & DNS are working as expected. Nslookup resolves the servers hostname correctly and vice versa, the same things when looking up the client from the servers perspective.

The problem only occures between these two machines.

Operation system used for clients is Windows 10 Pro 64bit.
The server uses Windows Server 2012 R2 and is hosted on VMware ESXI 6.
There's no subnetting, just one plain simple network.

Any idea?

Comment: Please give more information about the operating system and network configuration. Does "reach" mean "ping"?

Comment: @harrymc updated, let me know if you need more input

Comment: I assume there are other Windows 10 Pro clients in the network, are they all the same version? Is there possibly a firewall blocking the access?

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, Win10 Pro, that's absolutely correct. Windows integrated Firewalls are disabled, our FortiGate hasn't registered any internally blocked traffic

Comment: Other Windows 10 Pro clients can communicate with the problematic one? Is there only one DHCP server in the domain? Does `ipconfig` on the problematic client show anything different than on the others? Are IPv4&6 enabled the same on it as on the others? Is there only one network adapter?

Comment: @harrymc Only a single dhcp server in domain, All other network devices (means server / clients / switches / hub) can communicate with both of them. The problem only exists between those two. ip configuration is on both identical, ipv4 as well as ipv6 is enabled. Client as well as virtual server have only one nic.

Comment: I have no more ideas about what's wrong with that client, beside a strong-arm method such as [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out the issue. Or at least what is causing the problem.
It is the onboard network adapter of the win10 client. I've tried out a external network adapter connected via usb und everything worked fine again.

I think I'm not gonna bother anymore trying to reset the adapter and will simply reset the client. That's gonna be faster.